# How do I span css formatted text over fixed sized divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, smarty

I'm creating an online screenwriting program using HTML and CSS. The format of screenplays consists of scene headings, dialogs, and action elements. Each element is in a DIV with its own set of css rules (left and right padding and margins are the real differences). The formatting of the script is great. But now, I need to put the formatted text into pages. Meaning, once the formatted text reaches the bottom of the 8.5in x 11in DIV, it needs to be cut off and continue into the next div. Initially I was thinking I'd have to calculate the width and height of each different inner div element and then truncate when appropriate. Wonder if there's an easier way. I'm also using Smarty templates. I've attached a photo for reference[image: sample script]

```
<style>
    .screenbox {
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        background: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        padding: 5px 14px;
        color: #313131;
    }

    .screenbox li {
        font: 12px/14px Courier, fixed;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .sceneheader, .action, .character {
        padding-top: 1.5ex;
    }

    .action {
        padding-right: 5%;
    }

    .character {
        margin-left: 40%;
    }

    .dialogue {
        margin-left: 25%; padding-right: 25%;
    }
</style>
<ul class="screenbox">
    <li class="sceneheader">INT. INTERROGATION ROOM - DAY</li>
    <li class="action">Emily is sitting on a chair and has a police jacket sprawled over her back. Her face is covered by her hair and her hands are covered with caked-on blood and she's wearing handcuffs. Her boots are covered in dirt.</li>
    <li class="sceneheader">INT. POLICE STATION HALLWAY - DAY</li>
    <li class="action">A uniformed officer holding some plastic bag and a folder outside the interrogation room. Detectives Johnson and Evans approach. Johnson takes the folder. Evans takes the bags. Johnson opens the folder.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">What do we got?</li>
    <li class="character">POLICE OFFICER</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Suspected double murder in Jeff Park. No priors. She hasn't spoken. Been in there about an hour.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Another quiet one?</li>
    <li class="action">Johnson motions Evans to open the interrogation room door. Evans opens and they enter.</li>
    <li class="sceneheader">INT. INTERROGATION ROOM - DAY</li>
    <li class="action">Detective Johnson and Evans enter. Evans places the evidence bags in center of a table and sits down. Johnson stares at Emily for a bit almost as he's trying to read her mind. He eventually sits down. Johnson scans the evidence. In the bags are a red backpack, a crumpled photo of Emily, and an engagement ring. Johnson opens the folder and pretends to read it. Then closes the folder.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">I'm not going to lie, Emily. Even though you've got a clean record, it doesn't look good: double murder and you're carrying around evidence you been cheating on your fiancé. </li>
    <li class="action">Detective Johnson grabs the bag with the photo and shows it to Emily.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">He turns over the photo and reads the writing: "Dearest Kyle. Thanks for all the great times. Now time for more. Heart, Em". Heart Em. Sounds passionate to me, huh? And I think the jury would agree.</li>
    <li class="action">Johnson hands the photo to Evans who looks at the photo with more detail. Then looks at Emily. Evans holds the photo next to Emily's face to compare them.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE EVANS</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Hmm.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">What?</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE EVANS</li>
    <li class="dialogue">She looks a lot younger in this photo. Don't you think?</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Hehe, what do you expect? She's all covered in blood and dirt. Clean her up and the photo will match.</li>
    <li class="action">Johnson takes back the photo from Evans and returns it to the evidence bag. Johnson is in deep thought trying to think of another strategy. He looks at the engagement ring and grabs the bag. He pulls out the ring and looks at the blood on it.  </li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Won't be needing this anymore huh? Wanna take a look?</li>
    <li class="action">He extends the ring out to Emily. She tries to snatch it, but Johnson pulls away before she can grab it.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Tell you what, sweetheart. Tell me what happened, and I'll let you wear it for a little bit.</li>
    <li class="action">Evans is starting to get annoyed.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE EVANS</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Just leave her be. Her lawyer is on the way. </li>
    <li class="action">Evans tries to take the ring. Johnson pulls away still looking at Emily</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Hold on sec. So Emily. We got a deal?</li>
    <li class="action">Emily thinks and after a moment, she nods her head. Evans can't believe Emily agreed and that he's going to her hold the ring. Emily slowly reaches out and takes the ring. Johnson pulls in his chair and takes out his pen.</li>
    <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
    <li class="dialogue">Ok, now start at the beginning.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Printer should do this for you no?

Comment: Can you provide some code/snippet

Comment: A printer will cut words in half if not paginated

Comment: Added code snippet

Comment: Able to provide the compiled HTML? Well, enough to play with

Comment: ok added compiled HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Have you tried the `page-break-inside` property?

Here's an example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.screenbox {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  color: #313131;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.screenbox li {
  font: 12px/14px Courier, fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.sceneheader,
.action,
.character {
  padding-top: 1.5ex;
}

.action {
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.character {
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.dialogue {
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="screenbox">
  <li class="sceneheader">INT. INTERROGATION ROOM - DAY</li>
  <li class="action">Emily is sitting on a chair and has a police jacket sprawled over her back. Her face is covered by her hair and her hands are covered with caked-on blood and she's wearing handcuffs. Her boots are covered in dirt.</li>
  <li class="sceneheader">INT. POLICE STATION HALLWAY - DAY</li>
  <li class="action">A uniformed officer holding some plastic bag and a folder outside the interrogation room. Detectives Johnson and Evans approach. Johnson takes the folder. Evans takes the bags. Johnson opens the folder.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">What do we got?</li>
  <li class="character">POLICE OFFICER</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Suspected double murder in Jeff Park. No priors. She hasn't spoken. Been in there about an hour.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Another quiet one?</li>
  <li class="action">Johnson motions Evans to open the interrogation room door. Evans opens and they enter.</li>
  <li class="sceneheader">INT. INTERROGATION ROOM - DAY</li>
  <li class="action">Detective Johnson and Evans enter. Evans places the evidence bags in center of a table and sits down. Johnson stares at Emily for a bit almost as he's trying to read her mind. He eventually sits down. Johnson scans the evidence. In the bags are a red
    backpack, a crumpled photo of Emily, and an engagement ring. Johnson opens the folder and pretends to read it. Then closes the folder.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">I'm not going to lie, Emily. Even though you've got a clean record, it doesn't look good: double murder and you're carrying around evidence you been cheating on your fiancé. </li>
  <li class="action">Detective Johnson grabs the bag with the photo and shows it to Emily.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">He turns over the photo and reads the writing: "Dearest Kyle. Thanks for all the great times. Now time for more. Heart, Em". Heart Em. Sounds passionate to me, huh? And I think the jury would agree.</li>
  <li class="action">Johnson hands the photo to Evans who looks at the photo with more detail. Then looks at Emily. Evans holds the photo next to Emily's face to compare them.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE EVANS</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Hmm.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">What?</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE EVANS</li>
  <li class="dialogue">She looks a lot younger in this photo. Don't you think?</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Hehe, what do you expect? She's all covered in blood and dirt. Clean her up and the photo will match.</li>
  <li class="action">Johnson takes back the photo from Evans and returns it to the evidence bag. Johnson is in deep thought trying to think of another strategy. He looks at the engagement ring and grabs the bag. He pulls out the ring and looks at the blood on it. </li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Won't be needing this anymore huh? Wanna take a look?</li>
  <li class="action">He extends the ring out to Emily. She tries to snatch it, but Johnson pulls away before she can grab it.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Tell you what, sweetheart. Tell me what happened, and I'll let you wear it for a little bit.</li>
  <li class="action">Evans is starting to get annoyed.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE EVANS</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Just leave her be. Her lawyer is on the way. </li>
  <li class="action">Evans tries to take the ring. Johnson pulls away still looking at Emily</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Hold on sec. So Emily. We got a deal?</li>
  <li class="action">Emily thinks and after a moment, she nods her head. Evans can't believe Emily agreed and that he's going to her hold the ring. Emily slowly reaches out and takes the ring. Johnson pulls in his chair and takes out his pen.</li>
  <li class="character">DETECTIVE JOHNSON</li>
  <li class="dialogue">Ok, now start at the beginning.</li>
</ul>
```